How to use firebase email link sign-in without dynamic links
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};

import { getAuth, sendSignInLinkToEmail } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)
  .then(() => {
    // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
    // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
    // if they open the link on the same device.
    window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });

Above code reference - Email Link Authentication
I just want to use Email Link Authentication only for web platform
I tried removing following fields from actionCodeSetting:
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
};


According to this FAQ you need to contact Firebase support.
Apparently, Firebase is in a bizarre state where dynamic links are deprecated but required to support magic links.
